# Set Radio Button using value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set Radio button checked(select) using Attribute value

**html :**

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="radio" id="chairs_canadd" name="chairs_canadd" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" id="chairs_canadd" name="chairs_canadd" value="0" />
</div>
```

now i m getting the value of **chairs_canadd** value from database via AJAX. if the value is 0 then the second have to get selected , if the value is 1 then first one has to be get selected.

Comment: Why are you using `if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {`? Why are you using duplicate IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your IDs are not unique.

Second, a radio button group like this can only have one checked value at a time. So why not just use [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
$('input:radio[name=chairs_canadd]').val([editValue.chairs_canadd]);
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/z6xvF/)

Answer (score 1):

You have value for option that needs to be set in variable `chairs_canadd`. you can get the radio button by value and then set it. Like this:

```
$(".controls input[value="+chairs_canadd+"]").prop("checked", true)
```